# UICollectionViewCell did select item not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an issue with a collectionView inside a TableVieCell. When i tap on a collectionCell, didSelectItemAt doesn´t get called. I have a button in the collectionCell so i tried to disable the user interaction and enable the contentView userInteraction  but it didn't work.

[image: My Table cell]

The red rectangle is the tableCell and the blue rectangle is the collecionView insede the table view cell

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MedCellWithCollection") as? MedCellWithCollection{
                
                let backgroundView              =  UIView()
                backgroundView.backgroundColor  =  UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
                cell.selectedBackgroundView     =  backgroundView
                                
                cell.setMedName(name: self.medCatalog[indexPath.row].nombre, uso: self.medCatalog[indexPath.row].uso , array: self.medCatalog[indexPath.row].enfermedades[0].aplicaciones  , index: indexPath.row)
    
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                cell.layoutSubviews()
                cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
                cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
                
               
                return cell
            }
        
    }
   
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

The tableCell

```
class MedCellWithCollection: UITableViewCell {

//Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var medText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var uso: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var arrowIcon: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

//Variables
var dosesType:[Aplicacion]?


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.collectionViewSetUp()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


func setMedName(name: String, uso: String, array: [Aplicacion], index: Int){
    self.medText.text = name
    self.uso.text     = uso
    
    self.dosesType = array
    
    self.CollectionView.reloadData()
}


} 
extension MedCellWithCollection: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

func collectionViewSetUp(){
    self.CollectionView.delegate    =  self
    self.CollectionView.dataSource  =  self
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dosesType?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "doseColletion", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? DoseCollection {
        
            
        cell.setButtonConfig(doseType: self.dosesType![indexPath.row].metodo , index: indexPath.row)
            
            return cell
    }
    
    return UICollectionViewCell()
    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("tapped")
}

}
```

CollectionCell

```
import UIKit

class DoseCollection: UICollectionViewCell {

//Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var Button: Button!

//Variables
let constants = Constants()

func setButtonConfig(doseType: String, index: Int){
    
    self.Button.titleLabel?.text = doseType
    
    self.Button.backgroundColor = constants.COLOR_ARRAY[index]
    
    
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

override func layoutIfNeeded() {
    super.layoutIfNeeded()
}

}
```

Comment: Your table view cell should have no selection while the collection view should have single selection.

Answer (score 1):

**Potential Solutions:**

**1)** Should be Single Selection for tableView **selection** property, programmatically it can be done by `tableView.allowsSelection = true`

[image: table view Selection property]

**2)** The class is not the UITableViewDelegate for that table view, though UITableViewController is supposed to set that automatically.

```
tableView?.delegate = self
```

**3)** If the problem arise with UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("dismissKeyboard"))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

***BOL :)***

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I want to change the background of the button in other words the background of the cell in the collection view:

```
class CustomCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            grayBackgroundViewWithImage.image =
                isSelected ? UIImage(named: "") : UIImage()
        }
    }
```

In the main class where the collection view is stored create this variable:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

///save the indexPath of last selected cell
private var lastSelectedIndexPath: IndexPath? }
```

In viewDidLoad() set this value to false:

```
customCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

Further code in data source. In my case, the first cell should be is selected:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CustomCVCell.cellID(),
                                                  for: indexPath) as! CustomCVCell
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
        cell.isSelected = true
    }
    
    //update last select state from lastSelectedIndexPath
    cell.isSelected = (lastSelectedIndexPath == indexPath)
    
    return cell
}
```

Further code in the delegate:

```
///UICollectionViewDelegate
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard lastSelectedIndexPath != indexPath else { return }

         if let index = lastSelectedIndexPath {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: index) as! CustomCVCell
            cell.isSelected = false
          }

          let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCVCell
          cell.isSelected = true
    lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

[image: First Button isSelected by Default]
[image: tap the next!]
[image: more))]
[image: And finally, All works 100%]